Is there any way to ensure mbuf content is written back to memory before DMA operation
I'm writing my own PMD on Mediatek platform and encountering a problem on packet transmission while testing with testpmd utility provided by DPDK. I fixed the testpmd to verify only packet Tx on my driver.
Topology:
<platform> --eth cable-->>> <PC>
Symptom: While testing Tx burst from platform to PC, the transmitted packets were always defected and not complete by capturing on PC. (For example, packet contents are all zero or bunch of packets were missed)
What I have debugged:
I have been debugging by gdb to figure out possible root cause. I finally found it's probably caused by some cache mechanism over system level.
Looking into pkt_burst_transmit(), there are 2 main operation.
Operation 1. rte_mempool_get_bulk() + pkt_burst_prepare(): Prepared the packets for transmission
Operation 2. rte_eth_tx_burst: This will trigger the net device ops hook(.tx_pkt_burst) to operate platform DMA for packet transmission.
# Note: I applied huge pages for mempool.
In gdb debugging, I do 2 independent experiments

Set breakpoint at operation 1, packet memory are not requested from mempool and filled content at this moment. Then I execute "continue" to finish following jobs all in once(packet prepare + Tx packets). The result will get abnormal packet content(like all zero pkts) and miss most of packets transmitted by observing from PC.

Set breakpoint at operation 2, packets are well prepared at this moment(memory requested and contents are filled). Then executing "continue" to finish follow jobs all in once(Tx packets). Result in this case works perfectly and we can get complete packets on PC.


By concluding above experiments, I suspect packets are not writing back to memory as soon as I starting operating DMA transmission. In another word, packets content could not get ready before DMA accessing the packets memory for data movements.
I also tried:

I've tried to apply 0 cache size when creating mempool(rte_mempool_create_empty()) in testpmd to get a non-cached mempool, buut the problem resists. I thought there might be a further low level cache mechanism caused this problem.


Finally it's confirmed a cache coherency issue. It seems like the platform HW doesn't guarantee cache coherency automatically. My solution is to implement asm codes in userspace directly to flush mbuf cache to main memory before DMA transmission get triggered. Now it works well.
